# Get result that is the value (text) in one of 3 cells, with 3 conditions being combinations of 3 cells being blank or not blank. See image

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Three separate formulas and output value:

`=IF(D7&E7="",C8)` 
`=IF((AND(C8&D8<>"", E8="")),D8)` 
`=IF(E9<>"",E9)`

[image: Image of conditions and table, separate formulas and table]

Comment: Looks like there is a Hierarchy here Group 3 > Group 2 > Group 1. I think you already have the solution. Its just how you write the formula. You should be able to get it easily.

Comment: @Gangula    I can't get it - It's too deep for me, honestly.  I tried looking for something helpful on excel help sites, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Gangula - I was able to solve this by using a combination of 2 IF statements with an ELSE tagged on to substitute for the more complicated third condition.    

'=IF(D2&E2="",C2,IF(E2<>"",E2,D2))'

Thanks.